# Path is unknown when installing JustCloud

Tags: software-installation, paths

I am trying to install JustCloud on a new install of Ubuntu 14.04. [JustCloud on Linux/Ubuntu](http://www.ambience.sk/justcloud-on-linux-ubuntu/) says I need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install rdiff librsync1
sudo dpkg -i ./JustCloud_64.deb
```

before installing JustCloud.

Did the first one. The instruction on the second line says: "Change the second line to match the path to JustCloud package". I have no idea what to change that line to.

Comment: We have no idea what site instructions are you referring.

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the JustCloud_64.deb package to your Downloads folder, then the path to the JustCloud package is `~/Downloads`. If you downloaded the JustCloud_64.deb package to somewhere else, just drag the JustCloud_64.deb icon from the file manager into the terminal and it will automatically show the path to it.

The commands to use if you downloaded JustCloud_64.deb to your Downloads folder are:

```
sudo apt-get install rdiff librsync1  
cd ~/Downloads  # change directory to the path to JustCloud package
sudo dpkg -i ./JustCloud_64.deb  # install JustCloud
```

Comment: Thank you, software center shows JustCloud installed, but got dpkg: error processing justcloud (-install): subprocess installed post installation script returned error exit status 1 processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.-1)...

Comment: Try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get -f install` or if that doesn't work, you can remove JustCloud by running `sudo apt-get remove justcloud`.